# Best practice to handle animations in a XIB file and with minimum repeated code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have differents UIViewController that contains components that appear and disappear from the view (with animation like translation movment).
I would like to have a single class that reduce the amount of code in each UIViewController and that can be configured in XIB files.

So my XIB file contains :

- The component that need to move between two location (it's "My View" in the following screenshot)
- vVisible : A UIView that acts like an indicator to represent the visible location
- vHidden : A UIView that acts like an indicator to represent the hidden location

Here is what it looks like in XCode :

[image]

And I create a AppearingController (which is also a UIViewController). It controls the animation that make the component appear or disappear. It has 3 IBOutlet properties :

```
IBOutlet UIView * vVisible;
IBOutlet UIView * vHidden;
IBOutlet UIView * v;
```

And a public method (just that run the animation between the rect of the vVisible and the rect of the vHidden views) :

```
-(void) showVisible:(BOOL)visible {
CGRect frameDst = self.vVisible.frame;
if(!self.visible) frameDst = self.vHidden.frame;

CGPoint p = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(frameDst), CGRectGetMidY(frameDst));
self.currentPosition = p;

CABasicAnimation *frameTranslation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
frameTranslation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:p];    
frameTranslation.duration = 0.40;
frameTranslation.repeatCount = 1;
frameTranslation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
frameTranslation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
frameTranslation.cumulative = NO;
frameTranslation.additive = NO;
frameTranslation.delegate = self;
[self.v addAnimation:frameTranslation forKey:@"position"];
}
```

So, in my UIViewController code, I just need a few code :

- In the header file : the iboutlet/property to bind to the AppearingController instance of the XIB.
- In the implementation file : i can call [self.appearingController showVisible:FALSE] to run the animation to hide/unhide the component

**And ... it works**.
But I'm not quite satisfied because, I feel like it's a bit twisted and heavy. Because :

- The AppearingController is a UIViewController (I did not manage with object or external object from the objects library).
- vVisible and vHidden are views but I don't need view method/functionalities. I just need the view.frame to indicate the location.

This approach seems is good way to you ?

How can you improve it ?

Do you have some pattern you use to achieve this same goal ?

I'm interested

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems fairly good ! You can code this in a number of ways actually. But when it comes to this specific example, it does not matter if you want a better approach in coding. When you take up a much much bigger project it is necessary that you design your data structures and coding scheme such that you get it done in the most time constraint and optimized manner!

For example, In a much bigger project where you need to handle 100 images , you could just create a class for animation and subclass them accordingly and either reference them or inherit them so that your approach is logical and time-saving. Hope you got the point !